# UITextField input text position

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Hello
I'm making a custom UITextField like so :

```
_textField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;
_textField.backgroundColor = _color;
_textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
_textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
_textField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
_textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

The result I get is (image url) http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/4330/questionyd.jpg

**Question** : How do I move the input text slightly to the right so it doesn't touch the border ?
I suppose I must define some .frame property but can't figure which one.

thanks !
Louis

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `leftView` property with an empty `UIView` and a small frame, set the `leftViewMode` property to `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`, so your placeholder view is always used.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5)];
_textField.leftView = view;
_textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[view release];
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try creating your own subclass of `UITextField` and override the method:

```
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
```

Set your own bounds rather then deal with the default.