# Manage padding for a NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've create a subclass of NSTextField to manage its background color, text color, insertion point color and so on ...

I'd like to improve customized aspect of the objects from this class, but i can't understand how to manage size. If i change `frame.size.height` property the field grows from bottom but text's still placed at the top of the field.

Here a screen to describe what i mean:

[image]

I'd like to be able to manage a sort of "padding" and maintain text on the center of the field .

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722918/uitextfield-input-text-position
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439099/how-do-i-vertically-center-uitextfield-text

Comment: @TotumusMaximus i'm speaking about Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch.